# News Ticker - Pre-mature restart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, marquee, ticker

I'm trying to get this news ticker to work. For some reason it will restart after the 2nd list item, which is not what I want - I want it to rotate through the list items til the very end. What's wrong with this script?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbKHD/20/)

**HTML**

```
<h1>This runs differently than the ticker for some reason. It's highly annoying in my personal opinion.</h1>
<div id="ticker">    
    <div class="event">test1</div>
    <div class="event">test2</div>
    <div class="event">test3</div>
    <div class="event">test4</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.event{float: left; width: 100px;}​
```

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
(function($) {
        $.fn.textWidth = function(){
             var calc = '<span style="display:none">' + $(this).text() + '</span>';
             $('body').append(calc);
             var width = $('body').find('span:last').width();
             $('body').find('span:last').remove();
            return width;
        };

        $.fn.marquee = function(args) {
            var that = $(this);
            var textWidth = that.textWidth(),
                offset = that.width(),
                width = offset,
                css = {
                    'text-indent' : that.css('text-indent'),
                    'overflow' : that.css('overflow'), 
                    'white-space' : that.css('white-space')
                },
                marqueeCss = {
                    'text-indent' : width,
                    'overflow' : 'hidden',
                    'white-space' : 'nowrap'
                },
                args = $.extend(true, { count: -1, speed: 1e1, leftToRight: false }, args),
                i = 0,
                stop = textWidth*-1,
                dfd = $.Deferred();

            function go() {
                if (that.data('isStopped') != 1)
                {
                if(!that.length) return dfd.reject();
                if(width == stop) {
                    i++;
                    if(i == args.count) {
                        that.css(css);
                        return dfd.resolve();
                    }
                    if(args.leftToRight) {
                        width = textWidth*-1;
                    } else {
                        width = offset;
                    }
                }
                that.css('text-indent', width + 'px');
                if(args.leftToRight) {
                    width++;
                } else {
                    width--;
                }
            }

                setTimeout(go, 10);
            };
            if(args.leftToRight) {
                width = textWidth*-1;
                width++;
                stop = offset;
            } else {
                width--;            
            }
            that.css(marqueeCss);
            that.data('isStopped', 0);
            that.bind('mouseover', function() { $(this).data('isStopped', 1); }).bind('mouseout', function() { $(this).data('isStopped', 0); });
            go();
            return dfd.promise();
        };        
    })(jQuery);
        $('h1').marquee();
        $('#ticker').marquee();​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it in a container div

```
<div id="ticker-container">
<h1>This runs differently than the ticker for some reason. It's highly annoying in my personal opinion.</h1> <div id="ticker">    
    <div class="event">test1</div>
    <div class="event">test2</div>
    <div class="event">test3</div>
    <div class="event">test4</div>
</div>
</div>

$('#ticker-container').marquee();
```

Comment: But that doesn't really solve the problem. The ticker will go the length of the h1, but without the h1 it just restarts after the last 2. The h1 was just an example, the purpose of the script is to used as a news ticker, so test1-4 would be the events.